# changing theme of tinymce from modern to advance hide the textarea in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tinymce-4

I am trying to use fckeditor `tinyMCE` in my `mvc` project.

So i added this code to the header of my website :

```
  @Scripts.Render("//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js")
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // Initialize your tinyMCE Editor with your preferred options
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode: "textareas",
        theme: "modern",
    });
</script>
```

I added this to my model :

```
[AllowHtml]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string NewsText { get; set; }
```

And finally my view :

```
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsDate, new { @class = "control-label col-lg-2" })
       <div class="col-lg-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewsDate, new { @class = "form-control myfont" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.NewsDate, "", new { @class = "validation" })
      </div>
</div>
```

the result is :

[image]

Every thing works fine but when i am trying to change the theme of editor to advance i mean :

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        // Initialize your tinyMCE Editor with your preferred options
        tinyMCE.init({
            // General options
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "advance",
        });
    </script>
```

the `editor` is removed why ?

Answer (score -1):

Simple typo, should be "advanced" not "advance"